# How to authenticate Google Services in Google Colaboratory without user interaction?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-api-python-client

I use the following to access bouth Google Drive and Google Sheets in my Google Colab Notebook:

```
# Mount Google Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Google Sheets

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe
```

My problem with this is that it asks for the user to confirm the authentication in a pop-up and I want to use colabctl (https://github.com/bitnom/colabctl) to automate the execution of some scripts, so I need to execute the authentication part without user interaction.

Comment: there is `google.auth.load_credentials_from_file(...)` to load credential from JSON file - but you have to save correct values after first authentication. It can use also path from system variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. See documentation for [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guide.html#using-external-identities). Probably you could do the same with `driver` but it may need write own function to mount drive and this can be complicated.

Comment: example how to use [Driver API to access files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) - it also can read credential from file. But this needs use API functions to read data from file.

Comment: app-to-app auth in GCP is always handled with service accounts. You can create a service account in your project, copy the email of the service account, share the drive /folder access to the service account email and then authenticate to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a possible solution, I may suggest using `Service Account`.

1. Go to [GCP Console](https://console.developers.google.com)
2. Select your current project (or create a new one):
   [image: select GCP project]
3. Once the project is selected, go to `IAM and Admin` -> `Service accounts` -> `+ Create service account`: [image: create service account]
4. Next, you'll see a create service account prompt, which consists of 3 form steps. Fill in step 1 with any data you want. Skip steps 2 and 3.
5. You'll be redirected to the new service account page. Note an `Email` field there. You may share any Google Drive content for that email address (same as you do for users' personal email addresses).
6. Now you need to create a service account key, so you could use it to authenticate your script (select `JSON` key type):
   [image: create service account JSON key]
7. After step 6, you should get your `JSON` key file downloaded. Put it into your `Google Colab` files. You may do something like that to initialize your google client (`gc`) :

```
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='/content/credentials.json')
```

**Important:** `gspread` version should be `>=3.6.0` to support `service_account()` method.

**Note:** See my example to list all shared `Google Sheets` using `gspread`:
[image: personal notebook example]

Comment: Great answer, works like a charm. I will just leave this line of code here, so people can copy and paste instead of typing from the image: `!pip install gspread==5.4.0`